# Storing data in array and looping through, 1 element is blank

Tags: c, structure

I am new to C and working on a C project. I have defined a structure at the top of the file so it is available to everything in the file. My structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct NumberLookupStruct
{
    char * phoneNumber;
    char * displayName;
} numberLookupStruct;

struct numberLookupStruct *numberLookup = NULL;
```

Near the beginning of a function I malloc the structure and then call a function passing the structure to load the structure with data as follows:

```
numberLookup = malloc(totalLookupNumberCount * sizeof(numberLookup));
    if (numberLookup == NULL) return 1;

    int result = loadArray(HandleDB, resultReport, rowReport, &numberLookup);
    if (result) return 1;
```

The load array function has the following code:

```
int loadArray(MYSQL *HandleDB, MYSQL_RES *resultReport, MYSQL_ROW rowReport, numberLookupStruct *numberLookup)
{
    int sqlLen = 0;
    char *sql;

    sqlLen = asprintf(&sql, "SELECT * FROM TblLookups");

    SL_DebugAll(DBG_INFO, sql);
    if ((mysql_real_query(HandleDB, sql, sqlLen)))
    {
        printf("MySQL Error: %s\n", mysql_error(HandleDB));
        free(sql);
        return 1;
    }

    resultReport = mysql_use_result(HandleDB);

    int i = 0;
    printf("***LOADING ARRAY***\n\n");
    while ((rowReport = mysql_fetch_row(resultReport)))
    {
        numberLookup[i].phoneNumber = strdup((rowReport[0] != NULL && rowReport[0][0] != '\0')  ? rowReport[0] : "");
        numberLookup[i].displayName = strdup((rowReport[1] != NULL && rowReport[1][0] != '\0')  ? rowReport[1] : "");

        printf("Stored phone number%s  in %i: with Display Name: %s\n",
                numberLookup[i].phoneNumber, i, numberLookup[i].displayName);
        i++;
    }
    printf("***FINISHED LOADING ARRAY***\n\n");
    mysql_free_result(resultReport);
    free(sql);
    return 0;
}
```

It all appears to be working fine at this point. When I am printing out what has just been stored in the structure, the phone number and the display name are both printed to the console.

Later on in the function after loading the array, I then call a perform search. This function passes the structure, phone number, total rows within the structure and should loop through finding the number and return the display name.

However, for some reason, when I loop through the structure, the phone number is blank but there is a display name.

Below is the code.

```
char * performSearch(char * phoneNumber, int totalLookupNumberCount, numberLookupStruct *numberLookup)
{
    //printf("***Performing search for phone number: %s***\n", phoneNumber);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < totalLookupNumberCount; i++)
    {
        printf("*PHONE NUMBER: %s***\n", numberLookup[i].phoneNumber);
        //printf("Phone Number: %s\tDisplay Name: %s\n", numberLookup[i].phoneNumber, numberLookup[i].displayName);
        //if (strcmp(numberLookupStruct[i].phoneNumber, phoneNumber) == 0)
        if (strstr(phoneNumber, numberLookup[i].phoneNumber))
        {
            printf("***FOUND MATCH: Phone Number: %s, struct phone number: %s, display name: %s***\n",
                    phoneNumber, numberLookup[i].phoneNumber, numberLookup[i].displayName);
            return numberLookup[i].displayName;
        }
    }
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

I don't understand why I can successfully print what was stored in the structure within the load array function but when performing the search the 11numberLookup[i].phoneNumber11 is always blank all the way through but the `numberLookup[i].displayName` contains data.

**UPDATE**

Declaration prototype of LoadArray as requested below:

```
int loadArray(MYSQL *HandleDB, MYSQL_RES *resultReport, MYSQL_ROW rowReport, numberLookupStruct *numberLookup);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `numberLookup` as a pointer to `struct numberLookupStruct` which - thanks to C being case-sensitive - is an incomplete type. Change that declaration to:

```
numberLookupStruct* numberLookup;
```

You are passing a ** to `loadArray` instead of a pointer:

```
int result = loadArray(HandleDB, resultReport, rowReport, &numberLookup);
```

change to

```
int result = loadArray(HandleDB, resultReport, rowReport, numberLookup);
```

and figure out how to turn on warnings from your compiler so that it will tell you when you do this.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both ways but doesn't make any difference. The compiler warning shows up on both as well ``warning: passing arg 4 of `loadArray' from incompatible pointer type``

Comment: @Boardy What is the declaration of `loadArray` visible at the callsite? Because in the code you're showing us, `numberLookup` has the correct type.

Comment: I've added the prototype declaration for ``loadArray`` to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Boardy I stand corrected: it's not the same type (see edited answer).

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is working now, its just the string compare which is currently broken for some reason but that's something different

Answer (score 0):

Make change as below

```
numberLookup = malloc(totalLookupNumberCount * sizeof(numberLookupStruct));
```

i am suspecting strdup() in case of phone number is failing due to insufficient Storage space.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately no luck. The phone numbers are still blank